# How to change price range filter Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, filter

I'm aiming to change how the price range filter is displayed and works. I would like it to be like this:

[image: Price range]

Any ideas about how I would go about doing this?

Comment: do you mean change price interval? or you need full flow of how it is worked

Comment: I suppose full flow of how it works

Answer (score 1):

Just go to

> Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Layered navigation

and change *Price Navigation Step Calculation* to "Manual".
Then you can set : *Default Price Navigation Step* to any value as you want. 
Don't forget to flush cache.
Good luck!